# Print encoded string

Tags: python, encoding, mp3

I'm developing my own mp3 decoder using python but I'm a little bit stuck decoding the ID3 tag. I don't want to use existing libraries like mutagen or eyeD3 but follow the ID3v2 specification.

The problem is that the frame data is encoded in some format I cannot print, using the debugger I see the value "Hideaway" but it's preceded by some strange characters as you can see here:

```
'data': '\\x00Hideaway'
```

I have the following questions: what kind of encoding is that? how can I decode and print that string? do you think other mp3 files use different encoding in the ID3 tags?

By the way, I'm using a utf-8 declaration at the top of my file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

and I'm reading the file using the normal I/O methods in python (**read()**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characacters `\\x00` indicate that a single byte with a value of zero precedes the `H`. So, your string looks like this:

```
Zero - H - i - d - e ...
```

Usually character strings have letters or numbers in them, not zero. Perhaps this usage is specific to ID3v2?

Considering an IDC3v2 standard (http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure), we see that it is:

```
Frames that allow different types of text encoding contains a text
encoding description byte. Possible encodings:

 $00   ISO-8859-1 [ISO-8859-1]. Terminated with $00.
 $01   UTF-16 [UTF-16] encoded Unicode [UNICODE] with BOM. All
       strings in the same frame SHALL have the same byteorder.
       Terminated with $00 00.
 $02   UTF-16BE [UTF-16] encoded Unicode [UNICODE] without BOM.
       Terminated with $00 00.
 $03   UTF-8 [UTF-8] encoded Unicode [UNICODE]. Terminated with $00.
```

So, we see that the zero byte indicates ISO-8859-1 encoding, up to the next zero byte.

Your program might deal with this like so:

```python
title = fp.read(number_of_bytes)
if(title[0] == '\x00')
    title = title[1:].decode('iso8859-1')
elif(title[0] == ... something else ...)
    title = title[1:].decode('some-other-encoding')
...
```